# self-signed certificate - DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT - Angular 17

Tags: angular

I have this when consuming a certain API in Angular

[image]

I've already made several changes, but I can't resolve them. I tested with other APIs and with other APIs the application works correctly. I'm a beginner in Angular and have more ideas on how to solve it.

Comment: I have open a similar question and waiting to face out it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78200126/angular-17-ssr-on-localhost-is-not-fetching-data-from-the-net-core-backend-as-t
can anyone help us ?