# Angular 17 SSR + SSL on localhost is not fetching data from the .net core backend as the call comes from postman

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I really need help to face out this problem. I m running angular on localhost  with this command npm start

`"start": "ng serve  --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key --host=127.0.0.1"`

the website is working from the browser but when I try to point out to the url from postman (I am going to simulate the facebook crawler) the service could not retrieve the data from the backend and it is giving this error into the console output - coming up from mt custom http handler

```
ErrorHandlerService 0 - "Http failure response for https://localhost:7093/api/Product/LoadProduct/21275402: 0 undefined"
Error
    at eval (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/src/app/error-handler.services.ts:25:37)
    at _Observable.init (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/observable/throwError.js:5:51)
    at _Observable._trySubscribe (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/Observable.js:37:25)
    at eval (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/rxjs/dist/esm/internal/operators/catchError.js:14:31)
```

If I put the link, https://localhost:7093/api/Product/LoadProduct/21275402, into the browser still working and this is the ErrorHandler code

```
export class ErrorHandlerService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authservice: AuthService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log('ErrorHandlerService ' + error.status + ' - ' + JSON.stringify(error.message)); HERE
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401 &&
          } else {
            return throwError(() => new Error(errorMessage));
          }
        })
      )
  }
```

this started when I migrate to V17.0.3

If I comment out part of the interceptor i got thi error

```
HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: _HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'https://localhost:7093/api/Product/LoadProduct/21275402',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:7093/api/Product/LoadProduct/21275402: 0 undefined',
  error: TypeError: fetch failed
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12345:11
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:368:26)
      at Object.onInvoke (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14424:33)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:367:52)
      at _Zone.run (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:130:43)
      at eval (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:1191:36)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:403:31)
      ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
      at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:36) {
    cause: Error: self-signed certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:403:31)
        at eval (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14098:55)
        at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14098:36)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:36)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14411:33)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:36)
        at _Zone.runTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:174:47)
        at invokeTask (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:484:34)
        at TLSSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (c:/GitHub/iperedil/angularapp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:473:48) {
      code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
```